Var args in DoFn Source
I'm trying to create an Apache Beam source/sink using google.cloud.sql.connector. I would pass minimal parameters so code can be used in different condition. Here is my code:
class _PostgresReadFn(DoFn):
    def __init__(self,  instance_name: str, driver: str, query: str, **kwargs):
        self._instance_name = instance_name
        self._driver = driver
        self._query = query
        self._conn_args = kwargs

    def process(self, element):
        with Connector().connect(self._instance_name,  self._driver  , self._conn_args) as conn:
            cur =  conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(self._query )
            for record in cur.fetchall():
                yield record


class ReadAllFromPostgres(PTransform):

    def __init__(self, instance_name: str, driver: str, query: str, **kwargs):

        self._instance_name = instance_name
        self._driver = driver
        self._query = query
        self._conn_args = kwargs

    def expand(self, input_or_inputs):
        postgres_read_fn = _PostgresReadFn(
            self._instance_name, self._driver, self._query,  self._conn_args
        )
        return (
            input_or_inputs
            | Create([1])
            | "ReadAllFromPostgres" >> ParDo(postgres_read_fn)
        )

and here is my pipeline:
   pipeline
        | "ReadFromPostgres"
        >> ReadAllFromPostgres(
            "instance",
            "pg8000",
            "SELECT * FROM table limit 10",
            db="db",
            user="user",
            password="pwd",
            ip_type="public",
        )
        | "WriteToStdout" >> beam.Map(print)

When I run I get the error:
TypeError: _PostgresReadFn.init() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

You're passing self._conn_args as the last argument, but since **kwargs in Python collects all keyword arguments into a dictionary, you are actually passing multiple arguments instead of one.
postgres_read_fn = _PostgresReadFn(
    self._instance_name, self._driver, self._query, **self._conn_args
)

try this
